# PHP date of birth checker

Tags: php

I am currently using the following PHP code to check date of birth, the code uses the american mm/dd/yyyy although I'm trying to change it to the british dd/mm/yyyy.

I was hoping someone could tell me what to change:

```
function dateDiff($dformat, $endDate, $beginDate)
{
    $date_parts1=explode($dformat, $beginDate);
    $date_parts2=explode($dformat, $endDate);
    $start_date=gregoriantojd($date_parts1[0], $date_parts1[1], $date_parts1[2]);
    $end_date=gregoriantojd($date_parts2[0], $date_parts2[1], $date_parts2[2]);
    return $end_date - $start_date;
}

//Enter date of birth below in MM/DD/YYYY
$dob="04/15/1993";
echo round(dateDiff("/", date("m/d/Y", time()), $dob)/365, 0) . " years.";
```

Comment: Well, you *could* look up `explode()` and `gregoriantojd()` and figure it out by yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the explode is breaking up the string into an array, it is using the / as the separator.

So for us dates you would get

```
$date_parts1[0] = 04
$date_parts1[1] = 15
$date_parts1[2] = 1993
```

what you want is to swap the values at index 0 and 1.

try this:

```
$start_date=gregoriantojd($date_parts1[1], $date_parts1[0], $date_parts1[2]);
$end_date=gregoriantojd($date_parts2[1], $date_parts2[0], $date_parts2[2]);
```

**Edit, added correction from comment:**
also change the last line to

```
echo round(dateDiff("/", date("d/m/Y", time()), $dob)/365, 0) . " years.";
```

Comment: you also require to change for `date("d/m/Y", time())` along with that

Comment: I am using this method right now but I get the following error:
Warning: gregoriantojd() expects paramater 1 to be long string...

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use timestamp when saving dates.

```
echo time(); \\ 1316631603 (Mumber of seconds since the Unix Epoch - January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
```

It will give you a better control as the format is always in seconds. It is also easy to format to any date format, sort and perform calculations.

```
echo date("m/d/Y", 1316631603);             // as US format (09/21/2011)
echo date("d/m/Y", 1316631603);             // as British and Danish format (21/09/2011)
```

If you choose to use timestamp the answer to your question is:

```
$user_bdate = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y", "11/30/1978")->format('U'); // Convert a US date to timestamp

$time_diff = time() - $user_bdate; // Take current date and subtract the birth date

echo (int) ($time_diff / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)) . " years."; // 43 years.
```

Referrer:

- [php - What is a Unix timestamp and why use it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823376/678611)
- [PHP: time - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)
- [PHP: date - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [PHP: date_create_from_format - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php)

Comment: If you store the timestamp in the database, you can just limit your results to those who have birthdays in the same way with:
WHERE bdate <= time()+86400 AND bdate >= time()-604800

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a function to return the years given the birthday on that specific format you could use something like this to avoid passing much data on the function call:

```
<?php
    function get_age($birthdate){
        list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $birthdate);
        $time_birth =  mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
        return round( (time() - $time_birth) / (60*60*24*365) ) ;
    }

    //example, use dd/mm/yyyy
    $dob="04/15/1993"; 
    echo get_age($dob). " years.";
?>
```