# Get timestamp for date to 60 days

Tags: php, date, time

I have this date for timestamp like `1393516517`, but I need the timestamp for 60 days.

I tried this way:

```
( 24 * 60 * 60 ) * 60 = 5184000;
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: What does `i need the timestamp for 60 days.` mean? Do you need a timestamp for 60 days from now?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the timestamp for 60 days*"? (In any case, you're probably looking for http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: 24*60*60*60 is indeed equal to 5184000. That is correct. It's probably not what you want to know, but it is the answer to the question you're asking.

Comment: *(related)* [Why do we use strtotime() in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822821/why-do-we-use-strtotime-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1393516517 is called a UNIX timestamp and is the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT). This timestamp in particular corresponds to 02/27/2014 3:55 PM GMT.

If you want to add 60 days to a UNIX timestamp, then you do indeed need to add the number of seconds 60 days equals just as you do. So 1393516517 + 5184000 = 1398700517 which is 04/28/2014 3:55 PM GMT.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are trying to get a *Unix timeatamp* for a *date 60 days into the future* of your *start date*:

```
$date = new DateTime('@1393516517');
$date->modify('+60 days');
echo $date->format('U');
```