# PHP difference between time() and getTimestamp() object [Year 2038 bug]

Tags: php

What is the difference between:

```
$now = time();
```

and

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->getTimestamp();
```

By taking into account the 32-Bit INT limitations (a.k.a year 2038 bug) is it safe to use getTimestamp() in a 32-Bit system ?

***Edit:***

For further information about this problem, check this link: [What is a Unix timestamp and why use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822821/what-is-a-unix-timestamp-and-why-use-it)

Comment: "safe" -- what do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822821/what-is-a-unix-timestamp-and-why-use-it

Comment: @Jack M.: that link doesn't explain what exactly you're being afraid of.

Comment: *Safer* apparently: http://3v4l.org/Jeo1V#v520

Comment: 32-Bit systems have a limited INT value shorter than 64-Bit systems; thus in 2038, a 32-Bit system is apparently unable to store the time() INT number

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? What have you done, to confirm your Question?

Simple enough:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('5000-01-01');
var_dump($datetime->format('d.m.Y'));
var_dump($datetime->getTimestamp());
```

Output:

```
string(10) "01.01.5000"
bool(false)
```

So: No, you are not `save` in Using a TimeStamp from DateTime.

Anyway: Question might be a good reference, but can be easy be found out by testing.

The Sence about DateTime is not to get a Unix Timestamp. It is about avoiding a Unix Timestamp. See the answer from your own link from the comments: [What is a Unix timestamp and why use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822821/what-is-a-unix-timestamp-and-why-use-it)

Comment: That's not correct, the PHP manual says about DateTime::getTimestamp(): Gets the Unix timestamp. And it does work on a 64 bit system while it returns false on a 32 bit system when the Year-2038 problem applies.

Comment: The question is about 32 bit system @TorstenRömer

Answer (score 1):

Since `DateTime::getTimestamp()` returns the Unix timestamp which suffers from the Year-2038 problem on 32 bit systems it will return false on 32 bit systems when the Year-2038 problem applies (but still work on 64 bit systems).

So it is not safe to use on a 32 bit system I'd say.

Comment: With 64 bit, you will have `a bit` more time, but also this is limited. Unix Timestamps are not save!

Comment: I am trying to understand whether in a 32-Bit system, the getTimestamp() will return a "big" int, so I can store it as a string.

Comment: @Christian Gollhardt: If you don't expect your program to still be around after 15:30:08 on Sunday, 4 December 292,277,026,596 then it is perfectly safe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Solutions

Comment: @Jack M.: According to the PHP manual, `DateTime::getTimestamp()` will return false when the Year-2038 bug applies.

Comment: @JackM. `BigInt` is something in your DataBase (You will get this as string). Php can not native handle this Datatype. `getTimestamp` returns an integer. You should realy persistent your data as `DateTime` in SQL and work on PHP Side with `DateTime` object.

Comment: To summarize: Better stop using Unix timestamps in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: @JackM. Any language. SQL, Java, C#, (even XML or JSON)